# Url rewriting with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I’m a noob in url rewriting and i really need help to figure this out :

I have this url : section/news.php?url=section/news/27-how_to_make_rewrite.html I want to access this news with the url parameter and the link would be : section/news/27-how_to_make_rewrite.html

the .htacess file is in the root, i have a folder named section and inside this folder i have the news folder

This doest work for me.

I have :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /section/
RewriteRule news/^([a-zA-Z0-9-+/]+)/$ news/news.php?url=$1
```

How I can do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this with subfolders, but I would try something like this.

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/\.]+)/?$ news/news.php?url=section/news/$1 [L]
```

**Edit**

Try it this way:

```
RewriteRule ^section/news/([^/.]+)/?$ news.php?url=section/news/$1 [L]
```

You normally only want to put what is changing in the variable. section/news/ is always used so you should keep it outside of the replacement.

Comment: i have try this with no luck : RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ news/news.php?url=$1 i dont think i have to put the folders in the url like you did because the path is already in the url parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If the URI you want to rewrite *to* looks like: `section/news.php?url=section/news/27-how_to_make_rewrite.html`

then you've got one too many "news" in your target. You also need to fix your regex pattern to match stuff like `27-how_to_make_rewrite.html`.

You want something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /section/
RewriteRule news/(.+)/?$ news/news.php?url=section/news/$1
```